# Select first line in a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I got this table : 
[image]
I got this request :

```
SELECT FirstId,SecondId
FROM Table  
GROUP BY FirstId,SecondId
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN SecondId= 18 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 2 
END
```

So I got this result:
[image] 
But I want to get only the lines grouped by FirstId and ordered like the first request like this : 
 [image]

Comment: Why? what's the logic behind that desired result?

Comment: You need some kind of timestamp or rowid to get the "first request". Table data is un-ordered. There are no "first requests"...

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Rahul the secondId is linked to some user. I want to get the line attached to the current user, if it dosn't  exist, I take another line concerned by the firstId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT FirstId,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN SecondId = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 18 ELSE MAX(SecondId)
        END) as SecondId
FROM Table  
GROUP BY FirstId
ORDER BY FirstId;
```